# How to indirectly call out the sales team for not following leads as was agreed upon?

Tags: communication, colleagues

I'm a system engineer but went to an exhibition abroad with the CEO and COO as I'm the only one speaking fluent English. After returning we had a meeting together with the sales team (2 people directly below the CEO) and sorted out all new contacts (business cards) into  potential customers and everything else. Potential costumers were to be contacted by email by the sales team. I wrote an English email template for them to be used.

It's been three weeks and I haven't heard anything, nor was anything mentioned in their weekly reports. I strongly believe they never sent out a single email.
I believe it's a complete waste of resources to go to an exhibition if we don't follow up on leads.

This is east asia so I don't want them to loose face, but I also don't want to ignore it. How can I indirectly call them out for not following up on the leads.
Should I write a message on the company internal message board asking if there were any email replies that they needed English help with? Talking to the CEO seems like going behind their back.

Comment: You can ask them directly so you'll have an idea of what they did. But this is not your job to change anything or officially judge the waste of money, except if you are responsible for it. By the way, in east Asia (Japan for my experience), business cards mean almost nothing: one of their major purpose is to know how your contact is called and how to write his name. From a sale's point of view, it may not be really important.

Comment: I hope your email template doesn't refer to them as "costumers" ;-)

Comment: Are you selling fabrics or something?

Comment: _costumers_ are people making costumes. Perhaps you mean _customers_?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't your problem to address, nor do you know if it is even a problem for sure.

You did your bit, it's up to the CEO or COO or whoever is in charge of sales to follow up on what is a sales task.

While it may be a waste of resources, that is not your decision or responsibility.

Comment: That said, striking up friendly conversation about _how did that lead go_ isn't bad at all. He helped write the email, it's natural he would be curious if anything ever came out of it.

Comment: It's bad form to many people to put them up against a fence like that. I'd let it slide unless I had authority to do something about it.